# Finding non duplicate element in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am stuck in the following program:

I have an input integer array which has only one non duplicate number, say {1,1,3,2,3}. The output should show the non duplicate element i.e. 2.

So far I did the following:

```
public class Solution {

    public int singleNumber(int[] arr){
        int size = arr.length;
        int temp = 0;
        int result = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        int[] arr1 = new int[size];

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            temp = arr[i];
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                if(temp == arr[j]){
                    if(i != j)
                    //System.out.println("Match found for "+temp);
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {1,1,3,2,3};
        Solution sol = new Solution();

        System.out.println("SINGLE NUMBER : "+sol.singleNumber(a));
    }
}
```

Restricting the solution in array is preferable. Avoid using collections,maps.

Comment: The "cute" XOR-based solution could work...

Comment: Can you use another `Array`? if so I have a solution.

Comment: Is the array going to contain one and only one unique number?

Comment: @CoolGuy no but I think I found another solution, do the number to the power or 2, then take the original number and multiply it times each number, if it is ever equal to what is what when the number was taken to the power of two such as `3^2=9` and `3*3=9` then it is not unique and if no number is equal to the number then it is unique.

Comment: @jgr208 yes you can as much as you want but only arrays.

Comment: @CoolGuy may or may not be.

Comment: I think you can try using an HashMap to improve the performance.

Comment: @Leo Just for correction You have not used arr1 you have allocated a new memory but not used in the code -- int[] arr1 = new int[size];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is almost certainly a learning exercise, and because you are very close to completing it right, here are the things that you need to change to make it work:

- **Move the declaration of `flag` *inside* the outer loop** - the flag needs to be set to `true` every iteration of the outer loop, and it is not used anywhere outside the outer loop.
- **Check the `flag` when the inner loop completes** - if the `flag` remains `true`, you have found a unique number; return it.

Comment: Additionally, you could have your algorithm perfom a bit better if you start your inner "j" loop starting from i+1 instead of 0

Comment: @Joel If he does, the algorithm would return `1` on the second iteration of the outer loop, because there's no other duplicates for `1` when `i` is `1` and `j` is `i+1` or more.

Comment: in some case for example {2,2,1} it will return result as 0 i think means if nique number has last slot in array than not sure, i think we need reset flag in inner condition

Answer (score 12):

```
public class NonRepeatingElement {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int result =0;
    int []arr={3,4,5,3,4,5,6};
    for(int i:arr)
    {
        result ^=i;
    }

    System.out.println("Result is "+result);
}

}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation, not only raw code.

Comment: Here you have the explanation.
https://algorithmsbyme.wordpress.com/2012/06/05/find-the-only-non-duplicate-element-in-the-array/

Comment: This solution doesn't work for negative numbers and zero. Also if there are odd number of repletions.

Answer (score 1):

```
From Above here is the none duplicated example in Apple swift 2.0

func noneDuplicated(){    
            let arr = [1,4,3,7,3]    
                 let size = arr.count  
                 var temp = 0  
                 for i in 0..<size{  
                   var flag = true  
                   temp = arr[i]  
                     for j in 0..<size{  
                     if(temp == arr[j]){  
                        if(i != j){  
                            flag = false  
                            break  
                        }   
                    }   
                }    
                if(flag == true){   
                print(temp + " ,")   
                }  
            }  
        }

// output : 1 , 4 ,7
// this will print each none duplicated
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        /// for duplicate array 
        static void duplicateItem(int[] a){

                /*
                You can sort the array before you compare
                */

                int temp =0;
                for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<a.length;j++){
                        if(a[i]<a[j]){
                            temp = a[i];
                            a[i] = a[j];
                            a[j] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }

                int count=0;

                for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) {

                    for(int k =j+1;k<a.length;k++) {

                        if(a[j] == a[k]) {

                            count++;
                        }

                    }


                    if(count==1){

                        System.out.println(a[j]);

                    }

                   count = 0;
                }

            }


    /* 

       for array of non duplicate elements in array just change int k=j+1; to int k = 0; in for loop

    */
    static void NonDuplicateItem(int[] a){

            /*
            You can sort the array before you compare
            */

            int temp =0;
            for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
                for(int j=0; j<a.length;j++){
                    if(a[i]<a[j]){
                        temp = a[i];
                        a[i] = a[j];
                        a[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            int count=0;

            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) {

                for(int k =0 ;k<a.length;k++) {

                    if(a[j] == a[k]) {

                        count++;
                    }

                }


                if(count==1){

                    System.out.println(a[j]);

                }

               count = 0;
            }

        }

public class DuplicateItem {
    public static void main (String []args){
        int[] a = {1,1,1,2,2,3,6,5,3,6,7,8};
        duplicateItem(a);
        NonDuplicateItem(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    /// for first non repeating element in array ///
     static void FirstNonDuplicateItem(int[] a){

            /*
            You can sort the array before you compare
            */

            int temp =0;
            for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++){
                for(int j=0; j<a.length;j++){
                    if(a[i]<a[j]){
                        temp = a[i];
                        a[i] = a[j];
                        a[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }

            int count=0;

            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++) {
                //int k;
                for(int k =0; k<a.length;k++) {

                    if(a[j] == a[k]) {

                        count++;
                    }

                }


                if(count==1){

                    System.out.println(a[j]);
                    break;

                }

              count = 0;
            }

        }

public class NonDuplicateItem {
    public static void main (String []args){
        int[] a = {1,1,1,2,2,3,6,5,3,6,7,8};
        FirstNonDuplicateItem(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

not tested but should work

```
public class Solution {

    public int singleNumber(int[] arr){
        int size = arr.length;
        int temp = 0;
        int result = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        int[] arr1 = new int[size];

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            temp = arr[i];
            int count=0;
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                if(temp == arr[j]){
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count==1){
               result=temp;
               break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
public class Answer{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {1,1,3,2,3};
    int[] b =new int[a.length]; 
    //instead of a.length initialize it to maximum element value in a; to avoid
    //ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      int x=a[i];
      b[x]++;
    }
     for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
       if(b[i]==1){
       System.out.println(i); // outputs 2
       break;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

PS: I'm really new to `java` i usually code in `C`.

Comment: If the array contains numbers bugger than `a.length-1`,your code will throw an `ArrayOutOfBounds Exception`

Comment: @CoolGuy, That's why I added a comment at `line:4` of code.

Comment: Sorry. I haven't rad that comment when I was posting the comment. BTW,why don't you indent your code to make it more readable?

Comment: @CoolGuy, Thanks for suggestion, Done It. However I'm noob in editing So if you can edit that better than me, It'll be more acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I have a unique answer, it basically takes the current number that you have in the outer for loop for the array and times it by itself (basically the number to the power of 2). Then it goes through and every time it sees the number isn't equal to double itself test if its at the end of the array for the inner for loop, it is then a unique number, where as if it ever find a number equal to itself it then skips to the end of the inner for loop since we already know after one the number is not unique.

```
public class Solution {

    public int singleNumber(int[] arr){
        int size = arr.length;
        int temp = 0;
        int result = 0;
        int temp2 = 0;
        int temp3 = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        int[] arr1 = new int[size];

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            temp = arr[i];
            temp2 = temp*temp;
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                temp3 = temp*arr[j];
                if(temp2==temp3 && i!=j)
                    j=arr.length
                if(temp2 != temp3 && j==arr.length){
                    //System.out.println("Match found for "+temp);
                    flag = false;
                    result = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {1,1,3,2,3};
        Solution sol = new Solution();

        System.out.println("SINGLE NUMBER : "+sol.singleNumber(a));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dasblinkenlight...followed your method

```
public class Solution {

    public int singleNumber(int[] arr){
        int size = arr.length;
        int temp = 0;
        int result = 0;

        int[] arr1 = new int[size];

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            boolean flag = true;
            temp = arr[i];
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                if(temp == arr[j]){
                    if(i != j){
//                  System.out.println("Match found for "+temp);
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                    }
                }

            }
            if(flag == true)
                result = temp;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] a = {1,1,3,2,3};
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        System.out.println("SINGLE NUMBER : "+sol.singleNumber(a));
    }
}
```

One disastrous mistake was not enclosing the content of `if(i != j)` inside braces. Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding for learning then you can solve it with still more efficiently.

1. Sort the given array using merge sort of Quick Sort.
   Running time will be nlogn.
2. The idea is to use Binary Search.
   Till required element found All elements have first occurrence at even index (0, 2, ..) and next occurrence at odd index (1, 3, …).
   After the required element have first occurrence at odd index and next occurrence at even index.

Using above observation you can solve :

a) Find the middle index, say ‘mid’.

b) If ‘mid’ is even, then compare arr[mid] and arr[mid + 1]. If both are same, then the required element after ‘mid’ else before mid.

c) If ‘mid’ is odd, then compare arr[mid] and arr[mid – 1]. If both are same, then the required element after ‘mid’ else before mid.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way to do so..

```
    public static void main(String[] art) {
    int a[] = { 11, 2, 3, 1,1, 6, 2, 5, 8, 3, 2, 11, 8, 4, 6 ,5};
    Arrays.sort(a);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        if(j==0) {
            if(a[j]!=a[j+1]) {
                System.out.println("The unique number is :"+a[j]);
            }
        }else
        if(j==a.length-1) {
            if(a[j]!=a[j-1]) {
                System.out.println("The unique number is :"+a[j]);
            }
        }else
        if(a[j]!=a[j+1] && a[j]!=a[j-1]) {
            System.out.println("The unique number is :"+a[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Happy Coding..

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple loops the time complexity is O(n^2), So the effective way to resolve this using HashMap which in the time complexity of O(n). Please find my answer below,

`public static int nonRepeatedNumber(int[] A) {

```
Map<Integer, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<>();
int result = -1;

for (int i : A) {
  if (!countMap.containsKey(i)) {
    countMap.put(i, 1);
  } else {
    countMap.put(i, countMap.get(i) + 1);
  }
}

Optional<Entry<Integer, Integer>> optionalEntry = countMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1).findFirst();

return optionalEntry.isPresent() ? optionalEntry.get().getKey() : -1;
```

}
}`